# How to return variables from static void methods

Tags: c#, return, scope, void

I'm new to C# and strongly typed languages. I'm doing an assignment for university and my program now works as intended. But, I changed 2 static void method headings to have return types not realising doing so will result in marks being deducted.

```
Current method headings
static bool DispenseCash(double amount, int whichAccount, bool validAmount) and
static double WithdrawAmount(int whichAccount) must remain 

What they need to be.
static void DispenseCash(double amount) and
static void WithdrawAmount(int whichAccount)
```

I changed them because I didn't know how to return the variable amount from
    static void WithdrawAmount(int whichAccount) 
    and use it as a parameter in 
    static void DispenseCash(double amount).

I am forced to use both methods rather than solve the issue using one larger method.

Here is segments of my code to explain it all a little better. I have only included the relevant parts to keep this short.

```
int whichAccount = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
do
{
double amount = WithdrawAmount(whichAccount);
validAmount = DispenseCash(amount, whichAccount, validAmount);
} while (validAmount == false);

//end of relevant method calls in main

static double WithdrawAmount(int whichAccount)    
{
Console.Write("\nPlease enter how much you would like to withdraw: $");
double amount = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());       
return amount; 
}
//end WithdrawAmount
```

In the DispenseCash method that follows if it is instead static void DispenseCash(double amount) how can I pass int whichAccount and bool validAmount into it and return a bool validAmount from it.

```
private static bool DispenseCash(double amount, int whichAccount, bool validAmount)
{
int numOf20s;
int numOf50s;
double balenceMinusAmount = (accountBalances[whichAccount]) - Convert.ToInt32(amount); 

if((Convert.ToInt32(amount) >= 1) && (Convert.ToInt32(amount) % 50 == 0) &&   (balenceMinusAmount >= accountLimits[whichAccount]))
{

numOf50s = Convert.ToInt32(amount) / 50;
numOf20s = (Convert.ToInt32(amount) % 50) / 20;


Console.WriteLine("Number of 50's = {0}", numOf50s);
Console.WriteLine("Number of 20's = {0}", numOf20s);
accountBalances[whichAccount] = (accountBalances[whichAccount]) - amount;
return validAmount = true;
}

else
      {
          Console.WriteLine("Invalid entry");
          return validAmount = false;
      }
}
```

Remember I can not change the method headings at all. But I can call one of them or new methods inside of the methods. I have tried a few different things, but all attempts have failed.

Comment: Just a side note - if you have a method, function, (whatever it's called in your language of choice) that has some meaningful output, it  shouldn't be void. It sounds like your professor is a moron.

Comment: You can use out parameters in c# that can be updated inside a method: public void DoSomething(int arg1, int arg2, out int result)

Comment: They is required to not change the method signature. It doesn't include out parameters.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, hmm yeah out parameters do sound more acceptable. But is there no other way to put a value back into main without changing the method signature?

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by jdphenix, I am not sure why you are being asked to do it this way. It goes against basic programming principals. Perhaps we do not understand the full context of the question at hand.

The only way I can think of doing it would be to utilise static variables in your application.

```
private static double withdrawalAmount;
private static int selectedAccount;
private static bool isValidAmount;
```

Then utilise these in your required methods, e.g.:

```
public static void WithdrawAmount(int whichAccount)
    {
        Console.Write("\nPlease enter how much you would like to withdraw: $");
        withdrawalAmount = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    }
```

Comment: +1 for a workable solution, but eww gross... I try to pretend to be amazed by requirements that teachers put on programming assignments

Comment: Fully agree - its a horrible way to be "taught" (can you even call this teaching?!). Would be better to be taught functional programming in a static context.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I may be misunderstanding the problem, but yeah I does make it more convoluted then I would prefer.